# Error al convertir fecha seleccionada - Angular 8

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando un filtro entre dos fecha , **Fecha inicial** y **Fecha final** el filtro funciona perfecto trae los datos pero no trae los datos completos y es por que al momento de seleccionar las fechas y convertirlas al formato, las convierte pero les resta un día.

De esta forma estoy convirtiendo las fechas:

```
 FiltrarPorFechas(incial, final) {
    this.ListaUsuarios = [];
    const IniDate = new Date(incial);
    const EndDate = new Date(final);
}
```

Agrego una imagen con el debug y la conversion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en la imagen las fechas inicial y final llegan al método así **"2019-07-10"** y **"2019-07-31"** pero cuando trato de convertirlas les pone un día menos como se muestra en la imagen.

He tratado de utilizar **`moment`** **`formatDate`** y no funciona, no entiendo el por que y no quiero sumarle un día.

Alguien podría ayudarme ?

Comment: a mi me funciona `new Date("2019-07-10")`

Comment: No se si sea configuración o algo pero a mi no me funciona :(

Comment: Ya me dieron la solucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `moment` puedes probar parseando la fecha a modo **`UTC`**

```
moment.utc('2019-07-10')
```

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
FiltrarPorFechas(incial, final) {
    this.ListaUsuarios = [];
    const IniDate = moment.utc(incial);
    const EndDate = moment.utc(final);
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.